# Placing a Canvas within Canvas XAML

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I want to add a number of canvas to another canvas but the following code doesn't seem to work, the application compiles but only a blank window is displayed.  Ideally this would show the canvases in a diagonal line.

Here is my vb.net code:

```
 For r As Integer = 1 To 10

    X += 5
    Y += 5

    Dim c As Canvas = New Canvas()
    Dim s As SolidColorBrush = New SolidColorBrush

    s.Color = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0)
    c.Background = s


    c.Name = "cnv" + CStr(X)
    c.Margin = New Thickness(X, Y, 0, 0)

    cnvOverLay.Children.Add(c)
    cnvOverLay.UpdateLayout()
  Next
```

I have tried to add multiple buttons using `dim b As Button = new Button()` instead of creating a new canvas every time,  that worked fine.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Looks like a copy paste error to start with, Add(b) what is b?

Comment: @JohanLarsson Check edit, b was the name of the button when I tested to see if I can add buttons in the same manner

Comment: dude what you exactly want to achieve ??? multiple canvases inside a gride or itemControl please be clear with your requirement

Comment: @Prasad This particular application won't do anything useful.  I want to test a concept where I can draw multiple canvas by specifying their exact location without being constraint by grids.

Comment: Your child canvases all have zero width and height. And please note that Canvas defines the [Canvas.Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.left.aspx) and [Canvas.Top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.left.aspx) properties for positioning child elements. Margin is not intended for that.

Comment: @blaffie go ahead just a suggestion canvas uses absolute co-ordinated so use left,top,right,left to children of canvas , best of luck, if you get any problem, I'll try to help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot see the canvases be because the do not have a width and a height.

Comment: also you have to set Left and top also